# how can I do to use same variable name, but different data type in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, oop

I get error when I was assigned the different value in same variable name.

This is the error: cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String'
and this is the code:

```
var data: String

data = "datas|datas"
data = data.components(separatedBy: "|") as! [String]
debugPrint(data.first!)
```

or, this is for image in code type:

[image: imagecode]

I think, in PHP language, is more easier than Swift language. Because, in PHP language, this code is run as it should.

hope somebody help me out

Comment: PHP creates just new variable with new type, Swift - not. Just create variable with proper type. `data.components(separatedBy: "|")` already returns `[String]`, don't need to cast. You just can't assign it to `String`

Answer (score 2):

No you can't

```
let other = data.components(separatedBy: "|") as! [String]
```

you have to set a variable to only 1 type at a time , makeing `data` of type `any` will do the job but you have to cast

Comment: So, there is no way for solve this problem?. I mean, I just want to use same variable for that data, like PHP language. :(

Comment: in swift same variable can't have many types at a time unless it's `Any` type which is more bad

Comment: oh, I see. Thank you for your explanation, sir!

Comment: @HabieSmart You should try to understand why Swift prohibits this. By prohibiting this, it encourages you to give variables more meaningful names. For example, in this case both the unsplit and the split string are called `data`. However, if you call the split strings `splitData` (or whatever suits your context), it becomes very clear what you are doing just by reading your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just use array of strings always:

```
var data: [String]

data = ["datas|datas"]
data = data.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: "|") }
debugPrint(data.first!)
```